# Scoping issues with Jquery slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

I'm using slideToggle and wondering how to pass a variable to the callback function. It traces back undefined. Any ideas? Cheers!

```
$('.drop-box .button').click(function(){

    var target = $(this).parent();

    var myVar = $(this);    

    target.slideToggle(300, function(myVar){

        alert(myVar); // undefined
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `myVar` from the callback function's arguments. You don't need to pass in the variable, since it is already in scope.

```
target.slideToggle(300, function() {
    alert(myVar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `.slideToggle()` doesn't pass any parameters in to the callback you'll have to remove the parameter `myVar` from your callback's definition. As the callback parameter was hiding your variable the original variable comes back in to scope.

```
$('.drop-box .button').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).parent();
    var myVar = "hello";    
    target.slideToggle(300, function(){
        alert(myVar); // hello
    });

    return false;
});
```